# Flutter - Local_auth (Required security features not enabled)

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to get biometrics authentication to work again after updating the app I'm developing.
But I'm constantly getting the same error when activating it:

```
 PlatformException(NotAvailable, Required security features not enabled, null, null)
```

The current one in the store has no problems at all.

I'm using local_auth: 1.1.4
MainActivity.java has been converted to a FragmentedActivity
I'm doing a simple check to see if the biometrics are available. Which they are

```dart
bool canCheckBiometrics = await auth.canCheckBiometrics;
List<BiometricType> availableBiometrics =
await auth.getAvailableBiometrics();

print(canCheckBiometrics); //Returns true
print(availableBiometrics.toString()); //Returns [BiometricType.fingerprint]
```

After that I try to do the authentication

```dart
try {
    authenticated = await auth.authenticate(
        biometricOnly: true,
        localizedReason: 'Login with biometrics',
        useErrorDialogs: true,
        stickyAuth: false);
} on PlatformException catch (e) {
    print(e);
}
```

This returns:

```
PlatformException(NotAvailable, Required security features not enabled, null, null)
```

And this is what the plugin comments in the code say.

```
// Indicates the device does not have a Touch ID/fingerprint scanner.  
const String notAvailable = 'NotAvailable';
```

I'm not really sure what to check anymore. Is this something new I need to be aware of?

Really hope someone can help me with this issue!

Hope to hear!

Comment: I am waiting a few month to be fixed this issue but unfortunately this problem still exist. Did you solve that ?

Comment: If you haven't tried it yet, I've included a way to solve this error below, you can have a look.

Answer (score 7):

First of all, you need to **add** a **biometric authentication method** to your device from **settings**.

For example if you are using **Pixel 2 API 32 as Android Emulator**,

- Go to **Settings** inside android emulator.
- Go into **Security**
- Under the **Device Security** section, select **Pixel Imprint**
- Android will ask you to put your finger on the sensor, in this part you should click the **Touch Sensor** button from the **Extended Emulator Settings** of **Android Studio**.

[image: Extended Emulator Settings Pixel 2 API 32]

- After turning on fingerprint verification in this way, when you return to the application and try again, you will see that the error is gone.

Similarly, if you are trying with a real device or another emulator, you need to enable fingerprint authentication and try again.

Answer (score 6):

I recommend that you verify all capabilities before of try authenticate the user.

```dart
Future<bool> authenticateIsAvailable() async {
  final isAvailable = await localAuth.canCheckBiometrics;
  final isDeviceSupported = await localAuth.isDeviceSupported(); 
  return isAvailable && isDeviceSupported;
}
```

This way, you can call `localAuth.authenticate` only for phones that have credentials enrolled and probably don't have exceptions. Even though, catch the error if possible.

Answer (score 2):

Go to settings -> security -> fingerprint and add fingerprint lock.

If you are using Android studio emulator then keep in mind that Android Studio emulator provides fake fingerprint scanning.[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think you don't have a fingerprint activated yet, or you don't have permissions to use it, check the permissions and try again.

Check this out:

https://support.dashlane.com/hc/en-us/articles/203682911-How-to-set-biometric-authentication-or-a-PIN-code-to-unlock-Dashlane-on-Android

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and after debugging I discovered that keyguardManager was always null and causing the plugin to throw not enable exception. I had to change the below method in LocalAuthPlugin as follows:

```
private boolean isDeviceSupported() 
{
   if (keyguardManager == null) return false;
    return (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M && 
   keyguardManager.isDeviceSecure());
}
```

to

```
private boolean isDeviceSupported() 
{
   return (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M);
}
```

It worked for me, hopefully will work for you and others.